# DAO that emit events on save, update and delete

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have created several DAO classes (I am using Spring JDBC) and I want to emit events on save, update and delete so that I can update the search index as well.

One way would be to create the event emitting logic in each DAO but that would be a lot of repition. So I thought of using AOP and an "around advice", but I don't know if this is the correct "time" of using AOP. Are there other solutions which would be more fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this by using listeners.  The flow reverses itself a bit, in that the children classes utilize the parent class as a helper of sorts.

```
public abstract class AbstractCrudDao<T> {
    private Collection<Listener> listeners = new HashSet<Listener>();

    public void addListener(final Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    protected void doAction(CrudAction<T> crudAction)
    {
        for(Listener listener : listeners) {
             listener.beforeAction();
        }
        crudAction.doAction();
        for(Listener listener : listeners) {
             listener.afterAction();
        }
    }

    public interface CrudAction {
        void doAction();
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void beforeAction();
        void afterAction();
    }
}

public class CarDao extends AbstractCrudDao {
    public void create(Car car) {
        doAction(new CrudAction() {
            public void doAction() {
                //create car here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You could make a separate `Collection` of `Listener`'s for each CRUD operation, or change it to your liking anyway you want to.

Comment: Thank you for updating, however how can you specify the implementation of the create method in a subclass? Such as CarDao? I see how this works if you specify everything in the abstract dao, but not when you need to implement the actual logic in the subclass

Comment: That certainly looks more what I need, thanks! Not that your example of callback was bad either, but I was thinking about flexibility and API design. But how would you only invoke InsertListeners or UpdateListeners for instance? Do you create different versions of the CrudAction and use the instanceof operator?

Comment: I mean, when I insert stuff I only want to notify insert listeners, on update only update listeners and on remove only remove listeners.

Comment: I am really trying to not do this whole thing for you.  Do you think you could try to utilize this as an example?  How about you post a new question with where you get stuck at?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by creating an abstract baseclass for all CRUD dao's.  The base interface would take in some sort of callback mechanism, and would look something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractCrudDao<T> {
    public void create(T t, CompleteCallback completeCallback)
    {
        create(t);
        completeCallback.onComplete();
    }

    public abstract void create(T t);

    //same for read, update, delete

    public interface CompleteCallback {
        void onComplete();
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a far from complete example, but I think it showcases the idea of utilizing the callback as a trigger for completion.  You can expand the interface further for receiving onException events too.

If you are utilizing Spring's Transaction management, you may have to do some further adjustments based on whether or not you want your callback events to happen inside or outside of the transaction.

Personally, I wouldn't use AOP for this unless you don't own the DAO code, but even if that is the case, some other mechanism may be preferred.

Comment: I can see how this could work, however I got one question on the usage. Would you have implemented the callback listener in the service that index the object, or would you create an anonymous class that implements the interface and then use the search indexer inside it?

Comment: Well, it depends on who will be acting on the callback.  You may need to propagate the callback (via delegation of the callback) to the appropriate location.  At that point, you can either inline the implementation with an anonymous inner class or with a top level concrete implementation.

Comment: Nice, I will try to implement this. Like the idea of it :)

Comment: I am trying to get this to work with listeners instead. I have removed the callback argument. Do you know how it could have been done?

Comment: I have a create method where I want to notify all listeners for before action, then run create method, and then run all listeners for after action.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?  Perhaps you want to ask a new question?

Comment: I want to have list of listeners, and then on for example adding I want to notifiy all listeners before the adding, and then again after the adding. I can't do that with the callback approach. Or I could, but if I wanted the API to be just `add(someObject)` I can't. With listeners I don't have to pass a callback, it can be registered by Spring automatically.

Comment: So, then don't pass them in on the `create` method, instead add them and hold on to a reference to them, some implementation of a `Collection` should do.  Then, when create is called, invoke the `doBefore` method of your listeners, do create, then invoke the `doAfter` method of your listeners.  Obviously, you will need to iterate your listeners in a loop to invoke them.

Comment: And how would you do that? I tried but I don't manage to set it up since I want the actual create logic to be implemented in the subclasses. Could you show by an example?

Comment: I have added a second answer, very similar to the first.